# facing problem in andriod studio 3.2 can't run emulator my computer specs are 2gm ram and can not even build app

Tags: java, android

Unable to detect adb version, exit value: 0xc0000135. ADB depends on the Windows Universal C Runtime, which is usually installed by default via Windows Update. You may need to manually fetch and install the runtime package here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: your problem is different and your question title is different. Your question title should be "Windows could not find ADB"

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1F1qiaiNdnI

Answer (score 0):

Chech android studio pc requirements my friend . Your PC specs is very low

Comment: so what  min specs should required to run android studio